# Bi directional communications between two view controllers in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a main Container View controller which has a table view controller and another view controller. In table view I am displaying certain items which can be selected and grouped. This group details are shown on the view controller(like a summary). once grouped these items will no longer be in table view. If needed I can even ungroup them and add it back to table view.

So these two view controllers need to have a communication channel between them. What would be the best approach here ? Protocols or blocks ? Notifications are a strict no.

Answer (score 1):

The business logic of your application should be handled separately from the code that glues things into views — you're conflating model and controller.

So the items and the groupings would be maintained by a third class. Both view controllers would talk to it. They would nit talk to one another beyond transient UI information like, say, one saying "this was the specific item selected".

Answer (score 1):

A good way to think about it is to start with the goal of no direct communication.  Instead, both VCs have access to the application's model (usually a form of a singleton), and configure their state based on the state of the model.  In other words, the view controllers are stateful with respect to the app's model, stateless with respect to each other.

But sometimes vcs in the same container must communicate, like in a navigation controller when a selection is made.  That's typically done in prepare for segue.  The selection is conveyed to the vc being pushed, and then it carries on.  To the extent that vc needs to communicate back down the stack, I try to go by the first principal:  can it just change the model state and get popped, counting on its parent to notice the changes in viewDidAppear?

If I need further communication still, I begin to worry about my design, but the next place I go is KVO.  There again, view controllers are passive with respect to each other, watching the app's model for changes they care about.  I classify NSNotification in this category.  Even though it sounds like you want to rule it out, it's my third favorite idea after nothing.

While I'm editing here, I notice @Tommy has provided concise advice that I agree with (and consistent with my opinion here).  I'll leave the answer since it adds a little nuance.

Comment: I concur with the use of KVO, I think it is underused in some of these types of situations.  Oftentimes it ends up being the cleanest solution.